# android google maps v2 or v3 to recognize the polygon click event

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using android google maps v2 now and I have implemented polygon based on the lat/long and i would like to recognize the polygon click event .

But  was unable to do so. I would like to know should I use maps v3 as it has onClickListner for polygon-id or is there anything similar for google maps v2 ?

Please let me know.Appreciate any help .Thanks in Advance.

**Condition:**
I am looking to implement every state with different colours and onClick event for each polygon.
Please suggest  the best alternative for the above implementation.

Comment: There is no Maps V3 for Android. There may be one with that number for JavaScript maps, which you are welcome to try to use in a `WebView`. AFAIK, a polygon is not clickable in Maps V2.

Comment: Thank you for your time.Is polygon onclick present in v3 android ??

Comment: I repeat: There is no Maps V3 for Android.

Comment: oh sorry is polygon clickable in webview ??

Comment: That I cannot say, as I do not develop JavaScript maps with Google Maps, let alone try hosting them in a `WebView` -- sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I have just worked on something similar.  As best I can tell, there is no click event for polygons in Google Maps for Android API v2.  There are a couple of different solutions available that I won't go into.

The simplest method is to rely on `OnMapClickListener`.  Register the listener and receive `onMapClick(LatLng point)` callbacks from the `GoogleMap`.  Then use a point in polygon algorithm to determine if the click was inside one of the polygons on the map.

Reference:
[How can I determine whether a 2D Point is within a Polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test)

Comment: Also, to reiterate CommonsWare, there is presently no Maps API v3 for Android.